# What's wrong with this MySQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql, t-sql

Sorry because this is a noob question. I'm new with MySQL:

I wrote a query like this:

```
SELECT
    u.userid, u.alias, g.company_name,
 v.endtime - v.begintime AS duration, 
    u.status, u.service_starttime,
 u.service_expiretime, v.begintime, u.email
FROM
    company_users c, company_groups g INNER JOIN
    user_info u INNER JOIN vfon_log v 
    ON (u.userid = v.hostid) ON (g.company_id = u.company_id)
```

This query returns a syntax error:

```
Query : SELECT        u.userid, u.alias, g.company_name, v.endtime - v.begintime AS duration, u.status, u.service_starttime, u.service_ex...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON (g.company_id = u.company_id)
 LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 4
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000
```

I've spent 30 minutes looking, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Thank you so much for your helps

Comment: As you are using MySQL, you may want to change `v.endtime - v.begintime` to `TIMEDIFF(v.endtime, v.begintime) AS duration`, as this will give you a correctly formatted time difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ON (g.company_id = u.company_id)
```

should be after `INNER JOIN user_info u`

So it becomes

```
SELECT
    u.userid, u.alias, g.company_name,
 v.endtime - v.begintime AS duration, 
    u.status, u.service_starttime,
 u.service_expiretime, v.begintime, u.email
FROM
    company_users c, company_groups g 
INNER JOIN user_info u ON (g.company_id = u.company_id)
INNER JOIN vfon_log v  ON (u.userid = v.hostid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the `ON` statements on the wrong place. The standard solution is to add it directly after the join:

```
SELECT *
  FROM company_users c, 
       company_groups g INNER JOIN
            user_info u ON (g.company_id = u.company_id) 
       INNER JOIN vfon_log v 
                 ON (u.userid = v.hostid)
```

Or you can use brackets to get the correct `ON` linked to the correct `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM company_users c, 
       company_groups g INNER JOIN
            (user_info u INNER JOIN vfon_log v 
                 ON (u.userid = v.hostid))
            ON (g.company_id = u.company_id)
```

Comment: the second query works (I'm checking if it works fine, the first one fails :)

Comment: @Vimvq1987: The first query probably fails because there is an extra `)` at the end of the last `INNER JOIN`.  Note also that the table `company_users` is referenced in the `FROM` clause, but not used elsewhere in your query.

Comment: Yeah sorry, copy & paste without thinking. I removed the extra bracket, it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Your field is not `vbegintime` but `v.begintime`

Comment: Just saw it :). But after correcting that, the problem still exits

Answer (score 0):

I think it should b

```
 SELECT        u.userid, u.alias, g.company_name, v.endtime - vbegintime AS duration, 
u.status, u.service_starttime, u.service_expiretime, v.begintime, u.email
    FROM   company_users c, company_groups g 
                           INNER JOIN
                             (user_info u INNER JOIN vfon_log v  ON (u.userid = v.hostid)) 
                              ON g.company_id = u.company_id
```

Comment: I tried this, but:

Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'vbegintime' in 'field list'
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

In fact, I didn't write this query. Visual Studio automatically generated query based on the query I wrote

Comment: Chris Diver's answer is probably closer to the desired result.